# Algorithm for dispatching a certain number of hours into 6 groups of at least 18 and 2 of at least 15

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

Here's my problem : I'm part of a group of 8 teachers and we have to dispatch classes for next year. Each class is equal to a certain number of hours. We have several 8h classes, 4h classes, but also 1h classes, 3.5h, etc.

There are two categories of teachers : those who have to work 18h (6 of us) and those who have to work 15h (2 of us).

The number of classes is normally large enough that dispatching them is easy and some of us end up with some extra hours. But this year the number of hours we have to do (6 * 18 + 2 * 15) is almost equal to the total number of hours available and it seems to me that it's impossible to create a partition knowing that we can't do less than 18h or 15h.

So, I'm trying to find an algorithm which could dispatch those hours into groups, so that 6 of us have at least 18h and the other two at least 2h.

I've seen some paper on the subject (https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/09/Papers/096.pdf for instance), but none answer totally my problem.

So if anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: I'd throw an SMT solver at it (e.g., https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver)

Comment: Thanks you very much ! Would it work with half hours too ?

Comment: You'd need to work in integer units. That could be half hours (scale up by 2x).